# Python function to filter data from array

Tags: python, loops, filter

I have made function to loop trough array and filter the results.

```
def filter_data(data, match_d=None, trim_matches=False):
    result_matches = {}  # stores matched
    result_unmatches = {}  # stores not matched

    # loop every record in data
    for key, value in data.items():

        # match record with filter criteria
        for search_string, search_key_name in match_d.items():

            if search_string == value[search_key_name]:
                result_matches[key] = value
            else:
                result_unmatches[key] = value

    if trim_matches is False:  # return only matches
        return result_matches
    else:  # return all but matches
        return result_unmatches



data_dict = {0: {'name': 'one'},
             1: {'name': 'two'},
             2: {'name': 'three'},
             3: {'name': 'four'},
             4: {'name': 'five'}}

result = filter_data(data_dict,
                     match_d={'one': 'name', 'two': 'name'},
                     trim_matches=True)

print(result)

#returns: {0: {'name': 'one'}, 1: {'name': 'two'}, 2: {'name': 'three'}, 3: {'name': 'four'}, 4: {'name': 'five'}}

#expected {2: {'name': 'three'}, 3: {'name': 'four'}, 4: {'name': 'five'}}
```

When i use `trim_matches=False` in function call it works as expected, however when i use `trim_matches=True` it does not.

Reason it's looping the key trough every match and then records in both lists `result_matches` and `result_unmatches`, however i cant find an easy fix for it.

I could simply write `result_matches` then compare the `data` and remove matches from data when using `trim_matches=True`, but i dont want to add more code to function.

**Solution i am looking for** is to make this current function work somehow with as little additional code as possible. in other words i want this logic to work rather than add more lines of code to this function and change it in any way.

**Alternative solution** rewrite full function code and logic, but should be less code than currently used.

No includes allowed only pure Python.

**Edit:** Realizing that debugging was difficult i went ahead and colored and spaced the output, now its easy to see what's going on.

[image]

Comment: Set an additional variable before the inner for-loop, e. g. `matched = False`. If you find a match, set it `True`. **After** the inner for-loop, add the entry to `result_unmatches` if the variable is still `False`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sweet that worked! i tried something similar, but i was cough up with the complexity of the function and complexity data that was provided, i simplified it only before posting to StackOverflow, guess i should not be so lazy next time and make simple version of function to look for simple solution. 

Did not realize second loop is only doing the comparison with filter, assignment not necessary has to happen inside second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstracting your loops demonstrates why it's not working.

```
for i in (1, 2, 3):
    for j in (1, 2):
        if i == j:
            print('match', i)
        else:
            print('no match', i)

match 1
no match 1
no match 2
match 2
no match 3
no match 3
```

For each match, you're failing to match every other number, so when you add to your dict at this point you're adding everything.

Changing this to a for/else loop is an optimal way to determine when no numbers match.

```
for i in (1, 2, 3):
    for j in (1, 2):
        if i == j:
            print('match', i)
            break
    else:
        print('no match', i)

match 1
match 2
no match 3
```

Your function then becomes this:

```
def filter_data(data, match_d=None, trim_matches=False):
    result_matches = {}  # stores matched
    result_unmatches = {}  # stores not matched

    # loop every record in data
    for key, value in data.items():

        # match record with filter criteria
        for search_string, search_key_name in match_d.items():

            if search_string == value[search_key_name]:
                result_matches[key] = value
                break
        else:
            result_unmatches[key] = value

    if trim_matches:
        return result_unmatches
    return result_matches

# match: {0: {'name': 'one'}, 1: {'name': 'two'}}
# no match: {2: {'name': 'three'}, 3: {'name': 'four'}, 4: {'name': 'five'}}
```

Note that if your `data` dict has items with duplicate names, then the for/else loop won't work and will only get you the first match. To get every match, you can set a variable if *any* matches occur during the loop, and only mark it as "not matched" if the variable wasn't set.

```
for i in (1, 2, 3):
    matched = False
    for j in (1, 1):
        if i == j:
           matched = True
           print('match', i)
    if not matched:
        print('no match', i)

match 1
match 1
no match 2
no match 3
```

Comment: `data dict has items with duplicate names` i don't understand what you mean by that exactly? If i have `data_dict = {0: {'name': 'one'}, 1: {'name': 'two'}, 2: {'name': 'three'},3: {'name': 'four'},4: {'name': 'five'}, 5: {name: 'one'}}`, i.e. `{name: one}` used two times? `data_dict` is the data i am working with it could be repeating and have same value and it should be shown multiple times for all matching values.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, the first solution I gave is the cleanest, but if there were two records with `{name: 'one'}` then it would only get the first match.